# How use apache kafka in vertx, both on the server side, as well as the client?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, microservices, vert.x

I recently asked what was the best way to communicate my microservices in vertx, I did it in a way which was with a web client with the same library that provides vertx (it was very simple), however I have been reading that use apache kafka is better, but I do not know how to use it, I read the official documentation of kafka, but I could only create a producer and a consumer, I really do not know what to do with them, how can I from a microservice send a method to another miscroservice through kafka? Excuse my ignorance with the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your microservice can do that :

- Subscribe a Kafka topic and consume the messages from this topic and process that messages (to do that you need to create a consumer with a `group.id` in your microservice)
- Send messages in one or more topics to contact other microservices (to do that you need to create one or more producers in your microservice)

I recommend you to read some articles about microservices architectures using Kafka or old fashion JMS compliant system (like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ for example).

You can begin with this one : https://medium.com/@ulymarins/an-introduction-to-apache-kafka-and-microservices-communication-bf0a0966d63

Here is an example of scenario :

- Service A: a restfull endpoint to order a burger menu:

  `POST /v1/order`

  `{"type": "cheeseburger", "quantity": 1, "ketchup": true, "notify": ["cooker"]}`

  This service use a Kafka producer to send the JSON in a topic called `TOPIC_ORDERS`
- Service B: consume the messages of the `TOPIC_ORDER` and send a SMS to the cooker and insert the order in database and produce the created order with ids in another topic `CREATED_ORDERS`
- Service C: another restfull endpoint used by the cooker when the menu is cooked:

  `PATCH /v1/order/{id}`

  `{"ready": true, "notify": ["customer"]}`

  This one produce the message in the `TOPIC_ORDER` in order to call the service B to update the order in database and notify the customer.
- Service D: consume the messages of `CREATED_ORDERS` topic to index in a search engine used by some other applications (to make stats for example)

Comment: I'm sorry, could you give me a very simple example? of a microservice that through kafka use another microservice

Comment: I've update my answer but I think you need to do some research about oriented message architectures and microservices in general to understand the purpose of that and not focus on the technologies like Kafka or Vert.x